# Saving Drawable to Disk and retrieving - Android

Tags: android, save, drawable

how would I save a drawable to the SDcard (custom folder) and later retrieve it assuming im keeping track of the path of the saved item.

Thanks,
Faisal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to download images from Internet?

You can use `FileOutputStream` to save the images, and you can use `File.mkdirs()` to create custom directory on the SD Card.

If you want to load the image later, you can use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String pathName)`.

Comment: However how would I do this to a drawable?